# Web application deployment - checkout or not

Tags: web-server, python, deployment, web-applications, mercurial

When deploying a Python web application what are the pros and cons of using the following methods to deploy the application:

1. Use the VCS to make a checkout on the server
2. Use FTP/SSH/rsync to transfer a copy of a local checkout
3. Create a proper package and transfer that to the server

(Note 1 - I currently use method 1.  However my repository may contain many other project related artefacts as well as the actual application, so this seems to work best with SVN where I can check out only the relevant folder - with the DVCS all or nothing approach this looks like not such a good idea).
(Note 2 - I am currently switching to DVCS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go with 4: Have a clone on the server, and then make an archive of that and deploy that (as demonstrated in my [git push deployment tool, Giddyup](http://theshed.hezmatt.org/giddyup)).

The problems with the other methods, in my experience, are:

1. VCS checkout: Your checkout includes version control metadata, which (if you neglect to properly protect it with webserver configuration) can expose your source code to attackers or the terminally curious.
2. FTP/rsync: Nothing particularly wrong with this method, although a naive implementation (FTP, or rsync to an empty directory) takes a lot more time and bandwidth to transfer everything.  Also has an unpleasant habit of deploying stuff that wasn't checked in (always an adventure to diagnose *that* one), because it was just lying around your local working copy.  (You can work around this, but they mostly boil down to "make a local checkout", which devolves into (1).
3. Whilst I am a [packaging nut](http://hezmatt.org/~mpalmer/blog/2011/07/28/speaking-truth-to-idiots.html), I've found that packaging most(TM) webapps is overkill -- they're data, rather than program (from the point of view of the server), so wrapping it in a package ends up being unnecessary (assuming you've got a good deployment mechanism involving logging your deployments, exhaustively revision controlling them, and so on).

Comment: Re 1. Yes of course you need to hide .git/.svn in your web server, this is fairly trivial in most setups although can be forgotten (geek game => add '.svn' to any url).

Comment: Re 2. If using rsync you wouldn't normally go to an empty folder all the time, that's the point, but you're right that you would need to export to a clean folder first; however this would be locally, so is not quite the same as 1.

Comment: Re 3. Agree with you on that one

Comment: Re 4. Giddyup sounds interesting, but sounds rather similar to Fabric, of which I am already a fan.  But having a clone on the server still doesn't really answer Note 1, i.e. you still have stuff on the server that really has no business being there.

Comment: "can be forgotten" leads to "has been forgotten" leads to **pwned**.  So don't do that.  "You wouldn't normally" of course, but "a naive implementation" isn't "normal", just "all too common".  Why doesn't a clone have any place on a server?  It seems like a perfect place for it -- just not in your webroot.  And if you think Giddyup is like Fabric, then you're deeply confused about how one or the other of them works.